# Passing SQL query as system argument in Python

Tags: python, sql

I am trying to pass SQL query as an argument and store it into a Variable, so It can pick the query from the variable and execute SQL Statement. Is there any way? Appreciate your help in advance!

For example, I have a SQL query like;

```
Select column1, column2 from Table where Column3 = 'America' and column2 = %s
```

I need to pass this as a string to python file from Commandline and in the Python file I have;

```
state = 'NY'

conn = pyodbc.connect()
Query = sys.argv[1]
cur.execute(Query,[state])
```

When I am trying to do this way, I am getting the following error

```
 format_operation_with_parameters operation = operation % tuple(tlist) TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

Comment: How are calling the script and passing this in?

Comment: `pyodbc` uses `?` for placeholders, not `%s`.

Comment: Please paste the whole file (including imports). And be aware that passing SQL string as argument is bad idea in general.